# How to set advanced printer settings

Tags: c#

I have create a c# windows application and I want to set a printer advanced setting to each report  when crystal report will generate and take a automatic print of current report.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227042/printing-with-advanced-options-tray-selection-duplex-staple

Comment: Or this [article](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2008/11/programmatically-selecting-complex-printer-options-in-c-shar/)

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.