# Changing driver settings for printing a PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, axacropdf

How can I change settings in my printer (driver), before printing out a PDF?

To be more specific - I want to force my printer driver to use a printer settings instead of driver defaults - basically an equivalent of clicking Properties in a Print window (which opens printer-specific settings), then Advanced Setup and ticking "Use printer settings" checkbox which is by default unticked.

But it could be anything, for example changing dithering mode in a printer.

Here is the functioning code I'm using right now for printing a PDF using my network printer:

```
Dim PrinterName As String = "\\MyNetwork\ZDesigner ZM400 200 dpi (ZPL)"
Dim WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterName)

Dim PrintingPageSettings As New Printing.PageSettings()
Me.Text = PrintingPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName()

Dim isInstalled As Boolean = False
For Each InstalledPrinter As String In Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters()
    If (PrintingPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName() = InstalledPrinter.ToString) Then
        isInstalled = True
    End If
Next
If (isInstalled) Then
    AdobeAcrobatCOM.src = Path
    AdobeAcrobatCOM.printAll()
Else
    Me.Text = PrinterName & " not found"
End If
```

AdobeAcrobatCOM is `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF` (Adobe PDF Reader from Toolbox, COM components)

Comment: http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2008/11/programmatically-selecting-complex-printer-options-in-c-shar/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12157505/2319909

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563612%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used TCP connection to the printer and printed it out this way. Here is a code sample:

```
    Dim PrintString As String
    Dim ipAddress As String
    Dim port As Integer

    '123123 is sample integer, "TESTstring" is sample string, Space(2) is sample of adding (two) spaces
    PrintString = String.Concat("^XA", "^FO060,080", "^BXN,5,200", "^FD", "TESTstring", 123123, "%^FS", "^FO160,100", "^ACourier,14,14", "^FD", Space(2), "^FS", "^XZ")
    ipAddress = "ZDesigner ZM400 200 dpi (ZPL)" 'yes, this works too
    port = 9100

    'Open Connection
    Dim client As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    client.Connect(ipAddress, port)

    'Write ZPL String to Connection
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream())
    writer.Write(PrintString)
    writer.Flush()

    'Close Connection
    writer.Close()
    client.Close()
```

You might want to look for your printer documentation. [Here is a C# example for Zebra](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA301&actp=RSS).